# Error"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Type'

Tags: c#

I am getting an error for the sorting in the format "dd-mmm-yyyy" it should sort date,month,year wise when binding to grid

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Type'"

```
DataView dw = PurchaseRequestDetails.Tables[0].DefaultView;
DateTime NowDate = System.DateTime.Now;
string NewDate = NowDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
dw.Table.Columns["RequiredDate"].DataType = NewDate.ToString();

dw.Sort = "RequiredDate ASC";
foreach (DataRowView dr in dw)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("RequiredDate: " + dr["RequiredDate"].ToString());
}

dgvPurReq.DataSource = dw;
dgvPurReq.DataBind();
```

Comment: Use camelCase (instead of PascalCase) for local variables if you want to be consistent with the .NET Framework naming conventions.

Answer (score 3):

The error is in the line:
dw.Table.Columns["RequiredDate"].DataType = NewDate.ToString();

The DataType property gets or sets the type of data stored in the selected column.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx

Answer (score 2):

you are setting the data type of the column to the contents of the string which is the current date-time.  The current date-time is NOT a valid type.  Also, I am pretty sure that changing the data-type of an existing column with data in it will throw an exception as well.

if you remove these three lines

```
DateTime NowDate = System.DateTime.Now;
string NewDate = NowDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
dw.Table.Columns["RequiredDate"].DataType = NewDate.ToString();
```

I suspect this will work the way you are trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
string NewDate = NowDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
dw.Table.Columns["RequiredDate"].DataType = NewDate.ToString();
```

The second line is key; you're assinging a string (`NewDate.ToString()`) [to a property that accepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx) a `Type` as a value.

In .NET everything *has* a `Type`, but there are also instances *of* `System.Type`.  It's basically a special/specific class which describes another class (but isn't actually an instance of that class).  A rough simile is that it's like a blueprint--it describes something but it's not the real thing.h

To retrieve an instance of a `Type` you can use the [typeof()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs(VS.71).aspx) operator

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by setting the DataType to a type using typeof(DateTime) or DateTime.Now.GetType(). But what I dont understand is why do you do that? The DataView is returned with a list of rows and columns and from the code above, you are just using it, why do you want to change the data type?  Perhaps what you want is to format the data on display?

Comment: i need a sorting in this format according the date,year,month in server side coing dd-MMM-yyyy

Comment: Alright I get it now. But then your code is not representative enough. You have added the column and using it but you havent assigned the value to that new column.

Answer (score 1):

Please include the line number of the error next time... as that helps.
It seems that you're assigning a string to the DataType property of DataColumn, which expects a Type object. So the fix would be...

```
dw.Table.Columns["RequiredDate"].DataType = NewDate.GetType(); // or typeof(DateTime)
```

Update (for problem#2 - sort doesn't happen)
Adapted from the code snippet from [this MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) (look here for implementation of the helper methods).
Formatting of the DataColumn should be the responsibility of the presentation layer/consumer. However if you really need to do this in the DataView - [link](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.adonet/topic37560.aspx)

```
private static void DemonstrateDataView(){
   // Create one DataTable with one column.
   DataTable myTable = new DataTable("myTable");
   DataColumn colItem = new DataColumn("item",typeof(DateTime));

  myTable.Columns.Add(colItem);
   // Add five items.
   DataRow NewRow;
   for(int i = 0; i <5; i++){
      NewRow = myTable.NewRow();
      NewRow["item"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i);
      myTable.Rows.Add(NewRow);
   }
   myTable.AcceptChanges();
   // Print current table values.
   PrintTableOrView(myTable,"Current Values in Table");

   DataView secondView = new DataView(myTable);
   secondView.Sort = "item";

   PrintTableOrView(secondView, "Second DataView: ");
}
```

Output:

```
Current Values in Table
        8/10/2010 11:34:28 AM
        8/9/2010 11:34:28 AM
        8/8/2010 11:34:28 AM
        8/7/2010 11:34:28 AM
        8/6/2010 11:34:28 AM

Second DataView: 
        8/6/2010 11:34:28 AM
        8/7/2010 11:34:28 AM
        8/8/2010 11:34:28 AM
        8/9/2010 11:34:28 AM
        8/10/2010 11:34:28 AM
```

Comment: @vigna... it worked for me. Second DataView is sorted in Asc order of date. Compare your code against the above and look for differences.